# If I make a big batch of blueberry buttermilk pancakes and freeze them, how long will they stay fresh for before getting freezer-burnt?

Tags: freezing, fresh, pancakes

I love buttermilk pancakes. Being able to make them on the weekends for breakfast at a later date is just a bonus (like Eggo without the preservatives). I'm just not sure how long they last for in the freezer, as in, if they will ever get freezer-burn like meat does. I store them in individual ziploc bags for easy retrieval.

Comment: Eventually they do get freezer burn, but I've never tried timing it exactly. Most of the time they are eaten long, long before that.

How big a batch of pancakes are you talking about?

Comment: About 20? I average eating about 2-3 pancakes a month.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its going to depend on the type of packaging and also the freezer.

Lightly wrapped in plastic wrap (or worse, paper) will freezer burn fairly quickly. Vacuum-sealed will last much longer.

A self-defrost freezer with wide temperature swings will burn quicker. A manual defrost chest freezer much slower.

Worst case is probably around a month or less (not really sealed, freezer with wide temperature swings), best case (vacuum sealed in stable temperature chest freezer) over a year.

Answer (score 0):

I've stored pancakes in the freezer for over two month and not had any freezer burn.

I'm not sure what the "limit" is.